# How to initialize the element of char array to a 2d array in mips?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

According to the c code the value in the base address of array p is supposed to be equal value of base address of array str but they doesn't match I am still new to mips assbley so excuse me and feel free to do any edits thanks in advance
I think the problem is in loading bytes and storing bytes in the array but still can't figure it out,
I left extra parts of my assembly code in order to make it simple for the viewer of how the code is about but the part that I am asking about in specific is within the while loop

`this is the psudo code`

```
i=0;
j=0;
k=0;
while(j < my_strlen(str))
{
    if (str[j] == ' ')
    {
        p[i][k] = '\0';
        i++;
        k = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        p[i][k++] = str[j];
    }
    j++;
}
```

`this is my attempted mips code`

```
.data
 msg: .asciiz "Enter a string \n"
 str: .space 30       # get the paragraph from the user
 p: .space 400        #p[20][20]
    
 
 stringlen: .asciiz "String length is "
 blankSpace: .ascii  " "
.text
 main:

 la $a3,blankSpace
 lb $s4,0($a3)      # $s4 =blankspace
 

  la $s5,str      # address start of str
  la $s6,p        # address start of p
  la $s7,ptr1     # address start of ptrl
  li $t9,20       # width =20
  li $t0,0        # i=0
  li $t2,0        # j=0
  li $t3,0        #k=0
  
  
  WHILE:
  bge $t2,$s3,End_While   # branch if j<=strlength
  lbu $t7,($s5)           # $t7 = str[j]
  beq $t7,$s4,L           # if str[j]== ' ' branch L
  
  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # width *i
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array (width *i+k)
  sb $t7,($t8)            # p[i][k++]=str[j]
  addi $t3,$t3,1          # k++

  L2: addi $t2,$t2,1          # j++
      addi $s5,$s5,1          # str[j+1]
  j WHILE
  
  L:  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # array width * i 
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array +(width * i+k)  
  sb $zero,($t8)            # p[i][k++]='\0'
  addi $t0,$t0,1          # i++
  addi $t3,$zero,0        # k=0
  j L2           
  End_While:
```

`The whole programe`

```
.data
 msg: .asciiz "Enter a string \n"
 str: .space 30       # get the paragraph from the user
 ptr1 : .space 400     #ptr1[20][20]
 p: .space 400        #p[20][20]
    
 
 stringlen: .asciiz "String length is "
 blankSpace: .ascii  " "
 next: .asciiz "\n Next while"
.text
main:
 li $v0,4     
 la $a0,msg   
 syscall              # printing the message to the user
 
 li $v0,8
 la $a0,str
 li $a1,30
 syscall              # getting a paragraph from the user
 
 li $v0,4
 la $a0,stringlen     #"String length is "
 syscall
 la $a0,str
 jal strlen
 addi $a0,$v0,0
 addi $s3,$a0,0      #strlen value   $s3
 li $v0,1
 syscall              # calling the strlen function to count the string lengt     
 
 
 la $a3,blankSpace
 lb $s4,0($a3)      # $s4 =blankspace
 

  la $s5,str      # address start of str
  la $s6,p        # address start of p
  la $s7,ptr1     # address start of ptrl
  li $t9,20       # width =20
  li $t0,0        # i=0
  li $t2,0        # j=0
  li $t3,0        #k=0
  
  
WHILE:
  bge $t2,$s3,End_While   # branch if j<=strlength
  lbu $t7,($s5)           # $t7 = str[j]
  beq $t7,$s4,L           # if str[j]== ' ' branch L
  
  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # width *i
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array (width *i+k)
  sb $t7,($t8)            # p[i][k++]=str[j]
  addi $t3,$t3,1          # k++

L2: addi $t2,$t2,1          # j++
  addi $s5,$s5,1          # str[j+1]
  j WHILE
  
L:  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # array width * i 
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array +(width * i+k)  
  sb $zero,($t8)            # p[i][k++]='\0'
  addi $t0,$t0,1          # i++
  addi $t3,$zero,0        # k=0
  j L2           
End_While:
  
   
   li $v0,4     
   la $a0,p  
   syscall
 
  li $v0 ,10
  syscall            # Exit terminating the program

 strlen:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra,0($sp)
 addi $t0,$0,0      # i=0
 addi $t1,$0,0      # len=0
 l: add $t2,$a0,$t0    # add base address to offset
 lbu $t3,0($t2)     # load base unsigned for char array
 beq $t3,$0,finish  # if value of array[i] = '\0'
 addi $t0,$t0,1     # i++
 addi $t1,$t1,1     # len++
 j l

finish:
 subi $s0,$s0,1
 add $v0,$t0,$s0
 lw $ra,0($sp)        # restore old $s0
 addi $sp $sp 4 
 jr $ra
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole code? MARS says `ptr1` is undefined with this snippet. Also what seems to be a problem for sure is that you never increment `s5` in the loop, so you always checking `str[0]` and not `str[j]`.

Comment: @Eraklon I have added the whole program in a new section , could you illustrate the proper way for the increamentation ,I haven't used the ptr1 array yet thanks

Comment: when you increment `$t2` which is `j` increment `$s5` as well.

Comment: You incrementing `k` at the wrong place in WHILE. Put it after `sb`.